# Mac OS X accessing devices with same Vendor ID and different Product IDs

Tags: macos, usb

I am writing an application which opens USB devices and transfer some data. I am following the UsbSimpleNotificationExample from the Developer Examples. The example adds notifications and assigns callbacks for a unique Vendor ID and Product ID. But for my application I have multiple PIDs and a single VIDs. How can I add a dictionary entry with single Vid and more than one PIDs? If I use CFDictionarySetValue with 2 PIDs, the 2nd Pid call overwrites the first dictionary value. I am not able to match IOServiceAddMatchingNotification callbacks properly due to this. What are the other options I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try only adding the vendor ID?

Then your matches should include all the product IDs.

Comment: This is correct. Broaden your search and iterate through the results.

Answer (score 0):

6 years late...sorry.

Here's how you do it:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef  matchingDict = IOServiceMatching ( kIOUSBDeviceClassName );
if ( matchingDict )
{
    UInt32        usbVendor = k_MyVendorID;
    CFNumberRef   refVendorId = CFNumberCreate ( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &usbVendor );
    CFDictionarySetValue ( matchingDict, CFSTR ( kUSBVendorID ), refVendorId );
    CFRelease ( refVendorID );
    CFDictionarySetValue ( matchingDict, CFSTR ( kUSBProductID ), CFSTR ( "*" ) );   // This is a wildcard, so we find any device.
}
```

Note the wildcard.

Comment: For kUSBVendorID and kUSBProductID, #include <IOKit/usb/USB.h>